# What is the difference between loader or AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, loader

I want to know the difference between Android loader and AsyncTask ,
here the demo on Loader:

```
package com.android.loaderdemo;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.webprocessor.Http_GetServices;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks<String> {
    TextView txt_username, txt_userEmail, txt_password, txt_role, txt_secretQuestion, txt_answer, txt_zipcode;

    private static String url = "http://dotstg1.xyz.com/loud/webservcies/GetUserProfile.svc/GetUserProfile/124";
    static String response;
    static String name, email, Pasword, Answer, RoleId, SecretQuestion, Zip;

    static String useResult = null;

    static JSONArray userParams = null;

    private static final int THE_LOADER = 0x01;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e("onCreate", "onCreate");
        // getSuLoaderManager().initLoader(THE_LOADER, null, this).forceLoad();
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(THE_LOADER, null, this).forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        Log.e("onCreateOptionsMenu", "onCreateOptionsMenu");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Log.e("onCreateLoader", "onCreateLoader");
        SampleLoader loader = new SampleLoader(this);

        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> arg0, String arg1) {
        txt_username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txt_userEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        txt_password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
        txt_role = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.role);
        txt_secretQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secretquestion);
        txt_zipcode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zipcode);
        txt_answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

        txt_username.setText(name);
        txt_userEmail.setText(email);
        txt_password.setText(Pasword);
        txt_role.setText(RoleId);
        txt_secretQuestion.setText(SecretQuestion);
        txt_answer.setText(Answer);
        txt_zipcode.setText(Zip);
        Log.e("onLoadFinished", "onLoadFinished");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String> arg0) {
        Log.e("onLoaderReset", "onLoaderReset");

    }

    private static class SampleLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {

        @Override
        public Context getContext() {
            Log.e("getContext", "getContext");
            return super.getContext();
        }

        @Override
        public int getId() {
            Log.e("getId", "getId");
            return super.getId();
        }

        public SampleLoader(Context context) {

            super(context);
            Log.e("SampleLoader", "SampleLoader");
        }

        @Override
        public String loadInBackground() {
            Log.e("loadInBackground", "loadInBackground");
            try {
                response = Http_GetServices.connect(url);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject json2 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("GetUserPrfResult");
                String test = (String) json2.get("Descritption");
                JSONObject json3 = json2.getJSONObject("GetUserPrfParams");

                name = (String) json3.get("Name");
                email = (String) json3.get("Email");
                Pasword = (String) json3.get("Pasword");
                RoleId = String.valueOf(json3.getInt("RoleId"));
                SecretQuestion = String.valueOf(json3.get("SecretQuestion"));
                Answer = (String) json3.get("Answer");
                Zip = String.valueOf(json3.get("Zip"));

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Totally depends over: Your requirement, database table schema and relationship, if your table supports an auto-increment primary key and only one table data has to be displayed Loader is appropriate. While async tasks is best to save/update/delete etc operations, those which are short lived.

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/android-loaders-versus-asynctask.html

Answer (score 8):

From [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/android-loaders-versus-asynctask.html):

> One subclass of Loaders is the AsyncTaskLoader. This class performs
>   the same function as the AsyncTask, but a bit better. It can handle
>   Activity configuration changes more easily, and it behaves within the
>   life cycles of Fragments and Activities. The nice thing is that the
>   AsyncTaskLoader can be used in any situation that the AsyncTask is
>   being used. Anytime data needs to be loaded into memory for the
>   Activity/Fragment to handle, The AsyncTaskLoader can do the job
>   better.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion: Loader is better. because I used AsyncTask a year before , that's a really nightmare for me , because you can't control the whole progress immediately , like sometimes , there is also a asynctask run on the activity,but you want to quit the activity ,you should call `asynctask.cancel()` , but ,this method : `cancel()` is not cancel the asynctask straightway.so in this case ,you application will crash due to this . so , if you use asynctask , you must be careful about how to cancel the task .